# How to make full color brush in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I need to pint with full color image as brush. How can brush contain all colors from source image? I need something like clone stamp, but with predefined contents. Picture for better understanding [image]

Comment: No but you can copy and transform

Comment: GIMP does this. In fact, at the present time, I believe its the only application that does it well. There's also a plugin called Brush Factory for Paint.NET that can do this.  The interface is a bit clunky.  But it works.  Brush Factory is here:  https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/110673-brush-factory-v18-dec-10th-2018/

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop brushes do **not** contain color information. All color is derived from the foreground/background color settings and any brush dynamics, such as the Hue Shift setting.

**Brushes are greyscale images in all instances.** There is no way to alter that.

You may want to look into smart objects and duplicating those to create multiple instances of colored artwork. This would be the most efficient method. It would allow you to use the same tree over and over but you couldn't simply "brush" the artwork on.

Photoshop CC also has the **Tree Filter** located under `Filter > Render > Tree. . .` which is designed to create trees of various appearance. Exploring that may be of benefit depending upon what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

It is possible to get Photoshop to create multiple trees along a path using the `Tree` filter.

Answer (score 1):

a brush can only contain one color(hue and Saturation), but different alpha(brightness). you can't just put the image to brush preset, instead, you should turn it into black and white image first. and adjust the contrast to what you want(white area will be transparent and black area will be filled with the color when you are using the brush) , and select a high Saturation color when you are using the brush.

Comment: maybe there is another way to achive this result?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows (or can run Windows in a VM) and Paint Shop Pro is an option, the Picture Tubes feature does exactly this. (If it's for a single project, you could conceivably get away with a trial installation, but it's not particularly expensive in any case.) It's not a complete Photoshop replacement by any means, but there are a few things that PSP does that Photoshop doesn't do or doesn't handle nearly as neatly, so it's a good secondary program to have around.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for this a few months ago. The one alternative that I stumbled with (and it's free) is this:

https://krita.org/

Here's the explanation on how to do it:

https://youtu.be/fgA4BcO3Nq8

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please go into detail what the links you suggested are about.  At this time this is a link only answer which doesn't fit within SE's format.  Please make an [edit] with more detail or this may be removed because it could be considered spam.

Comment: Upvoted but agree with Darth. A bit more info would be nice at least on the explanation side.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Mixer Brush under Brushes in the tool palette.

Make the brush large enough to cover your whole image that Option-Click (alt click) to make the brush.

Use 100% hard & save from the brushes palette.

Note: at this time I don't think mixer brushes have the option to rotate.